# how to remove duplicate results from mysql query in php?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to provide a search function for my PHP site. The users should be able to search rows and columns for their desired query, like "search engine". I tried this php code:

```
<?php
    $con = @mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "search");
  $output = '';

  if(isset($_POST['search'])) {
    $search = $_POST['search'];
    $search = preg_replace("#[^0-9a-z]i#","", $search);

    $query = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM sites WHERE (site_title LIKE '%$search%' or site_link LIKE '%$search%' or site_keywords LIKE '%$search%')") or die ("Could not search");
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    if($count == 0){
      $output = "There was no search results!";
    print $output;

    }else{

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {

    $site_keywords = $row ['site_keywords'];
    $site_tit = $row ['site_title'];
    $site_link = $row ['site_link'];

    $output .='<div> '.$site_tit.''.$site_keywords.''.$site_link.'</div>';
    print $output;

      }

    }
  }
?>
```

Everything works just fine but I'm getting duplicate results. I've read a lot of answers and here's I've done so far: I used `SELECT DISTINCT * FROM ....`  and also `SELECT DISTINCT site_id FROM ....` but didn't return any result. I tries GROUP BY but they didn't remove the duplicates and returned nothing. I also applied PHP array_unique() on `$row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)` in where condition, but it also didn't return any result.
If I can do this by using only SQL please or I have to remove duplicates by PHP like using a function, please guide me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wait a sec. You get duplicates and so you switch to `SELECT DISTINCT site_id FROM... ` and you get NOTHING? I don't believe it. At any rate, @manassehkatz has definitely found an issue in your PHP that may be more of a culprit than your sql.

Comment: @ suppresses warnings. Is that useful in development code?

Comment: Note: The object-oriented interface to `mysqli` is significantly less verbose, making code easier to read and audit, and is not easily confused with the obsolete `mysql_query` interface. Before you get too invested in the procedural style it’s worth switching over. Example: `$db = new mysqli(…)` and `$db->prepare("…")` The procedural interface is an artifact from the PHP 4 era when `mysqli` API was introduced and should not be used in new code.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or **any** user data directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Comment: You're right my friend, SELECT DISTINCT site_id FROM... returns nothing and SELECT DISTINCT * FROM... have no effect on removing duplicates.

Comment: I know this code is far from secure, but my I fix that in the end, I'm a better pentester than a web developer! :), my problem is with how to provide my user with a working search funcion...

Comment: thank you @tadman, I'll look into it, seems very interesting. But eventually I have to get mysql query right.

Comment: **WARNING**: Using the error-suppressing YOLO operator (`@`) obscures problems with your code and makes debugging issues like this a whole lot more complicated. That's a tool of last resort and should only be used in exceptional circumstances. You should display an error message for the user, log a problem, initiate some kind of retry, or all of these things in conjunction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move:

```
print $output;
```

outside the loop.

Right now `$output` is being printed every time through the loop. If your results are `A,B,C` then your output will be `A,A,B,A,B,C` (with divs, etc.)

Comment: Thank you my friend, I feel like such an idiot! This worked wonderfully, now I don't have to set my hair on fire!

Comment: @MrJay - I've had things in loops before that didn't belong. As long as we learn from our mistakes and move onward & upward, we'll all be OK.

Comment: I'm too familiar with these minor fails that ruin everything, I'm quite good at python but when you're on new territories things just get confusing! Thank you again @manassehkatz and my best wishes to you.

Comment: @MrJay I have much more experience with PHP than Python (though my biggest customer at the moment is almost all Python). In Python loops are real obvious - no worry about matching braces. On the other hand, **having** to indent can be annoying too.

Comment: yes @manassehkatz , python is almost too easy compared to many programming languages.  I learned c++ and java years ago but python makes everything so simple that have made me lazy. C++ drives me insane now, with all that pointers and such. First I wanted to use Django or Flask for my website but in the end PHP won because most of my website is in HTML and JavaScript and didn't need to use python that much... It seemed PHP is a more reasonable choice, given that I had studied it too some time ago. sometimes these minor adjustments in the language you're working on takes time getting used to.

Comment: The other advantage of PHP is hosting. It is trivial to find hosting for PHP sites. Django usually means setting up everything yourself (e.g., with AWS) or being very limited in options.

Comment: Of course you're right. PHP is much more hosting friendly. It's the go to language for website development. But using Django or Flask with a cheap VPS also works fine, just takes more effort. There are far more CVEs for PHP than Flask and Django but considering it's a much more popular option and it's much older than python frameworks, I assume bugs would be found and fixed faster... This is based on this assumption that they have security in mind more than developers working on newer frameworks...

Comment: PHP itself doesn't have a lot of CVEs, but using it without the support of a framework will expose you to a lot of huge risks. The same goes for any language without a framework. You won't have any CVEs because your site will be the first and only to be exploited. Frameworks are a herd defense: You're unlikely to be the first to get hit, so you'll most likely have time to patch.